# how to get direct link of youtube video and in different resolutions?

Tags: javascript, php, youtube

My problem is I wanna get the direct link of a YouTube video and different links for different quality. For example, if I have this URL [www.youtube.com/watch?v=VCQ24gXfRrc](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VCQ24gXfRrc) then direct links of this video in different quality are as follows

[for 240p](https://r1---sn-npo7en7y.c.docs.google.com/videoplayback?sver=3&expire=1416749747&ms=au&id=o-AIgwh2WIdnWUS7zwzHkiVFxUHkfYQT-oy-AD3PjxSVnl&mv=m&mt=1416728086&mm=31&source=youtube&initcwndbps=13747500&ip=128.199.133.159&signature=9E432598CB5D6077E55EA8B1335690B5CC26C40A.5A99F7921A144832A191265D3D2972FD2CB01EAC&fexp=901803%2C904843%2C907259%2C916640%2C921094%2C927622%2C932404%2C943909%2C945264%2C947209%2C947215%2C948124%2C949417%2C952302%2C952605%2C952901%2C953912%2C957103%2C957105%2C957201&itag=36&ipbits=0&sparams=id%2Cinitcwndbps%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Cmm%2Cms%2Cmv%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&upn=XNCHvFfgQJE&key=yt5&title=Best%20Babies%20Laughing%20Video%20Compilation%202014%20[NEW%20HD]%20vimow)

[for 360p](https://r1---sn-npo7en7y.c.docs.google.com/videoplayback?sver=3&expire=1416749747&ms=au&id=o-AIgwh2WIdnWUS7zwzHkiVFxUHkfYQT-oy-AD3PjxSVnl&mv=m&mt=1416728086&mm=31&source=youtube&initcwndbps=13747500&ip=128.199.133.159&signature=799CFF910B1C0DFFE12730CAE931AF10B13BB59E.A8E4705785ED8E891FED0E72173F8D88BB3225D9&fexp=901803%2C904843%2C907259%2C916640%2C921094%2C927622%2C932404%2C943909%2C945264%2C947209%2C947215%2C948124%2C949417%2C952302%2C952605%2C952901%2C953912%2C957103%2C957105%2C957201&itag=18&ratebypass=yes&ipbits=0&sparams=id%2Cinitcwndbps%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Cmm%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cratebypass%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&upn=XNCHvFfgQJE&key=yt5&title=Best%20Babies%20Laughing%20Video%20Compilation%202014%20[NEW%20HD]%20vimow)

[for 720p](https://r1---sn-npo7en7y.c.docs.google.com/videoplayback?sver=3&expire=1416749747&ms=au&id=o-AIgwh2WIdnWUS7zwzHkiVFxUHkfYQT-oy-AD3PjxSVnl&mv=m&mt=1416728086&mm=31&source=youtube&initcwndbps=13747500&ip=128.199.133.159&signature=C40202020E531DC84A619ED26B811890EB54A04D.D2BE78FADFF64AEA9854B2F6A006BBD89DB6663F&fexp=901803%2C904843%2C907259%2C916640%2C921094%2C927622%2C932404%2C943909%2C945264%2C947209%2C947215%2C948124%2C949417%2C952302%2C952605%2C952901%2C953912%2C957103%2C957105%2C957201&itag=22&ratebypass=yes&ipbits=0&sparams=id%2Cinitcwndbps%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Cmm%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cratebypass%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&upn=XNCHvFfgQJE&key=yt5&title=Best%20Babies%20Laughing%20Video%20Compilation%202014%20[NEW%20HD]%20vimow)

Can anyone tell me how to get direct links of YouTube video from Youtube? I've been searching a lot but couldn't find any solution. Any solution in PHP and javascript will be helpful.

Comment: This was discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23145257/is-there-a-way-to-link-someone-to-a-youtube-video-in-hd-1080p-quality

Comment: youtube is blocked in pakistan so i cannot use this procedure. i wanna grab direct link to video @AdibBehjat

Comment: That sucks. I was googling around and found that there is a special page within Google for 'downloading' videos. More can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8662109/using-get-video-on-youtube-to-download-a-video - the only issue is if youtube domain is blocked in Pakistan, wouldn't any requests be hampered?

Comment: Just a warning, some of the information in the links are private, I can see your IP address for example.

Comment: Are you looking for a something like youtube.2tera.com

Answer (score -1):

You can use this code:

```
videoUrls = ytplayer.config.args.adaptive_fmts
            .split(',')
            .map(item => item
            .split('&')
            .reduce((prev, curr) => (curr = curr.split('='),
                Object.assign(prev, {[curr[0]]: decodeURIComponent(curr[1])})
        ), {})
        )
        .reduce((prev, curr) => Object.assign(prev, {
                [curr.quality_label || curr.type]: curr
            }), {} );
```

output is json with different qualities:

```
        {720p: {…}, 480p: {…}, 360p: {…}, 240p: {…}, 144p: {…}, …}
    144p
    :
    {bitrate: "105451", lmt: "1501151759670299", quality_label: "144p", type: "video/webm;+codecs="vp9"", projection_type: "1", …}
    240p
    :
    {bitrate: "236138", lmt: "1501151763073149", quality_label: "240p", type: "video/webm;+codecs="vp9"", projection_type: "1", …}
    360p
    :
    {bitrate: "431019", lmt: "1501151763523043", quality_label: "360p", type: "video/webm;+codecs="vp9"", projection_type: "1", …}
    480p
    :
    {bitrate: "751515", lmt: "1501151761884798", quality_label: "480p", type: "video/webm;+codecs="vp9"", projection_type: "1", …}
    720p
    :
    {bitrate: "1530639", lmt: "1501151774338090", quality_label: "720p", type: "video/webm;+codecs="vp9"", projection_type: "1", …}
    audio/mp4;+codecs="mp4a.40.2"
    :
    {url: "https://redirector.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?k…70E2C77F1747DA9B3&source=youtube&mime=audio%2Fmp4", type: "audio/mp4;+codecs="mp4a.40.2"", init: "0-591", projection_type: "1", bitrate: "96956", …}
    audio/webm;+codecs="opus"
    :
    {url: "https://redirector.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?k…AEF92557AE5C5581&source=youtube&mime=audio%2Fwebm", type: "audio/webm;+codecs="opus"", init: "0-271", projection_type: "1", bitrate: "116254", …}
    audio/webm;+codecs="vorbis"
    :
    {url: "https://redirector.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?k…FA29AC0F6C925E21&source=youtube&mime=audio%2Fwebm", type: "audio/webm;+codecs="vorbis"", init: "0-4082", projection_type: "1", bitrate: "77114", …}
    __proto__
    :
    Object
```

Comment: but this code won`t work at mobile devices. If someone know how to fix it please share solution with us )